# Issue creating a script with dual logic in deeming a website online

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently trying to create a script that allows me to check multiple web url's in order to see if they are online and active. My company has multiple servers with different environments active (Production, Staging, Development etc.) I need a script that can check all the environments URL's and tell me whether or not they are online each and every morning so I can be ahead of the game in addressing any servers or websites being down.

My issue however is I can't solely base the logic strictly on an HTTP code to deem the site online or not, some of our websites may be online from an HTTP standpoint but have components or webparts of the site that is down displaying an error message on the page.

I am having trouble coming up with a script that can not only check the HTTP status as well as scan the page and parse out any error messages and then write to host based on both pieces of logic whether or not the site is "Online" or "Down"

Here is what I have so far, you will notice it does not include anything regarding parse for key words as I don't know how to implement...

```
#Lower Environments Checklist Automated Script


Write-Host Report generated at (Get-date)

write-host("Lower Environments Status Check");

$msg = ""
$array = get-content C:\LowerEnvChecklist\appurls.txt
$log = "C:\LowerEnvChecklist\lowerenvironmentslog.txt"


write-host("Checking appurls.txt...One moment please.");

("`n---------------------------------------------------------------------------        ") | out-file $log -Append

Get-Date | Out-File $log -Append

("`n***Checking Links***") | out-file $log -Append
("`n") | out-file $log -Append

for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
    $HTTP_Status = -1
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($array[$i])
    $HTTP_Request.Timeout =60000 
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

    If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
    $msg =  $array[$i] + " is ONLINE!" 
    }
    Else {
    $msg = $array[$i] + " may be DOWN, please check!"
    }
    $HTTP_Response.Close()
    $msg | Out-File $log -Append -width 120
    write-host $msg
}

("`n") | out-file $log -Append
("`n***Lower Environments Checklist Completed***") | out-file $log -Append

write-host("Lower Environments Checklist Completed");
```

**appurls.txt** just contains the internal URLs I need checked FYI.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you have a good question here since you are just saying it does not do what you want it to do. You do not give any examples of the other tests you want to do. Aside from that I think you need to have a CSV input with urls and test configurations.

Comment: Hello Matt, apologies if my question isn't coming in clearly. I've scoured the internet for tips on how to code what I'm trying to do but no dice, I figured I could leverage someones knowledge here to see if they knew a way to not only check a website for its HTTP response code as well as scan the page for error messages and then spit back whether or not the site is online based on both pieces of logic.

Comment: Again that is still open ended. What do you intend to look for when it comes to _error messages_? Are you expecting to look for text that says error? This is very context dependent so I think you would need to be providing specific examples. Right now its a crap shoot no one can code as there are too many variables. If there were keywords to look for you could save those and check for their presence possibly.

Comment: The error messages that would need to be included in the logic are **"An error has occurred" "Oops" "Unable to display widget data" "An unexpected error occurred" "temporarily unavailable"**

Comment: OK that is at least something to work with.

Comment: Any luck? I have been messing around with the 'switch -wildcard' option but not sure if the way I have it setup (via HTTP response) is actually scanning page content.

`for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
 $HTTP_Status = -1
 $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($array[$i])
    $HTTP_Request.Timeout =60000 
 $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
 $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode
 
 If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
      switch -wildcard ($HTTP_Response.content) {
    "*An error has occurred*
     *oops*
     *JBoss*
     *401* `

Comment: Should also be noted that I have upgraded to Powershell v3.0

Comment: Hi there, happy new year! Any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to at least give you an idea what to do. Need to capture the website data in order to parse it. Then we run a regex query against that which is built from an array of strings. Those strings are texts that might be seen on a page that is not working.

```
# build a regex query of error strings to match against. 
$errorTexts = "error has occurred","Oops","Unable to display widget data","unexpected error occurred","temporarily unavailable"
$regex = ($errorTexts | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"

# Other preproccessing would go here

# Loop through each element of the array
ForEach($target in $array){
    # Erase results for the next pass in case of error.
    $result, $response, $stream, $page = $null

    # Navigate to the website.
    $result = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($target)
    $response = $result.GetResponse()
    $stream = [System.IO.StreamReader]$response.GetResponseStream()
    $page = $stream.ReadToEnd()

    # Determine if the page is truly up based on the information above. 
    If($response.StatusCode -eq 200){
        # While the page might have rendered need to determine there are no errors present
        if($page -notmatch $regex){
            $msg = "$target is online!"
        } else {
            $msg = "$target may be DOWN, please check!"
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "$target may be DOWN, please check!"
    }

    # Log Result
    $msg | Out-File $log -Append -width 120

    # Close the connection
    $response.Close()
}

# Other postproccessing would go here
```

---

I wanted to show what a here-string looked like to replace some of your `out-file` repetition. Your log file header used to be several lines of this. I have reduced it to one.

```
@"

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(Get-Date)
***Checking Links*** 

"@ | Out-File $log -Append
```

Also consider CodeReview.SE for critiquing working code. There are other areas which could in theory be improved but are out of scope for this question.

Comment: Awesome! this worked great, only issue I'm having is for sites that require authentication, they are being listed as "may be DOWN" not sure why that is, the status should still be 200, any idea? Also is there a known command to have the logfile open automatically after the script runs? Thanks a ton Matt!

Comment: @KyloRen The authentication sites would be down since the would return status would be code 403. `Invoke-Item $log` just in case.